# Showing Sezzle Widget text after Afterpay Widget text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify

I am trying to get the "Sezzle text" below the "Afterpay" widget text

Please refer to the below image

[image: Screenshot]

I have Added this script in the script tag

```
<script>
  ymaps.ready(function() {

    if (ymaps.geolocation.country == "New Zealand") {
      $('#afterpay-block').css({"display": "block"});
    } 
         else if (ymaps.geolocation.country == "Australia") { 
      $('#afterpay-block').css({"display": "block"});
    }
           else if (ymaps.geolocation.country == "United States") { 
     
              $('.sezzle-checkout-button').css({"display": "none"});
             $('#afterpay-block').css({"display": "block"});
              $('.sezzle-button-text').css({"display": "block"});
             $('#shopify-zip-prod-widget').css({"display": "none"});
             $('#klarna').css({"display": "none"});
             $('#klarna-text').css({"display": "none"});
             
           
            
    }
    else {
      $('#afterpay-block').css({"display": "none"});
    }


  });
</script>
```

I am aware I could not hide a block and display it again in the same block. I was trying to hide it before "Afterpay Widget" and then show the "Sezzle" widget after the "Afterpay Widget". But obviosly it is not working

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div style="display: none" id="afterpay-block">
        <div class="sezzle-hide">
        <!-- Begin Afterpay Liquid Snippet for Shopify v2.2.0 -->
        {% assign afterpay_minimum_value_in_cents = 10000 %}
        {% assign afterpay_maximum_value_in_cents = 100000 %}
        {% assign afterpay_logo_theme = 'colour' %}
        {% assign afterpay_count_eligible_variants = 0 %}
        {% assign afterpay_supported_currencies = 'AUD, CAD, USD, NZD' | split: ', ' %}
        {% if afterpay_supported_currencies contains shop.currency %}
          {% for afterpay_variant in product.variants %}
            {% if afterpay_variant.available and afterpay_variant.price >= afterpay_minimum_value_in_cents and afterpay_variant.price <= afterpay_maximum_value_in_cents %}
              {% assign afterpay_count_eligible_variants = afterpay_count_eligible_variants | plus: 1 %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (
          function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
            i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments);
            },i[r].l=1*new Date();
            a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async=1;
            a.src=g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m);
          }
        )(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','afterpay_ga');
        afterpay_ga('create', 'UA-105673112-1', 'auto');
        afterpay_ga('send', 'event', 'Liquid Snippet', 'Report Version', '2.2.0');
        afterpay_ga('send', 'event', 'Theme', 'Report Name', {{ theme.name | json }});
        afterpay_ga('send', 'event', 'Shop', 'Report Currency', {{ shop.currency | json }});
        </script>
        {% if afterpay_count_eligible_variants > 0 %}
          <p class="afterpay-paragraph" style="display:{% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price >= afterpay_minimum_value_in_cents and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price <= afterpay_maximum_value_in_cents %}block{% else %}none{% endif %};" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}">
            Make 4 interest-free payments of
            <strong><span class="afterpay-instalments">${{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price | divided_by: 4.0 | round | money_without_currency }}&nbsp;{{ shop.currency }}</span></strong>
            fortnightly with 
            <a style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:10px;" href="https://www.afterpay.com/terms" target="_blank">
              <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://static.afterpay.com/integration/product-page/logo-afterpay-{{ afterpay_logo_theme }}.png" srcset="https://static.afterpay.com/integration/product-page/logo-afterpay-{{ afterpay_logo_theme }}.png 1x, https://static.afterpay.com/integration/product-page/logo-afterpay-{{ afterpay_logo_theme }}@2x.png 2x, https://static.afterpay.com/integration/product-page/logo-afterpay-{{ afterpay_logo_theme }}@3x.png 3x" width="75" height="15" alt="Afterpay" />
              <span style="font-size:12px;"><u></u></span>
            </a>
          <span id="klarna-text">or with</span> 
            <a style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:10px;" href="yourwebsite.com/pages/buy-now-pay-later-australia" target="_blank">
              <img id="klarna" style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://x.klarnacdn.net/payment-method/assets/badges/generic/klarna.svg" srcset="https://x.klarnacdn.net/payment-method/assets/badges/generic/klarna.svg" alt="Klarna" />
              <span style="font-size:12px;"><u></u></span>
            </a>
          </p>
          {% if product.price_varies or afterpay_count_eligible_variants < product.variants.size %}
            <script type="text/javascript">
              if (typeof Afterpay === 'undefined') {
                var Afterpay = {products:[]};
                Afterpay.loadScript = function(url, callback) {
                  var script = document.createElement('script');
                  script.type = 'text/javascript';
                  if (script.readyState) { // I.E.
                    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                      if (script.readyState == 'loaded' || script.readyState == 'complete') {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        callback();
                      }
                    };
                  } else { // Others
                    script.onload = function() {
                      callback();
                    };
                  }
                  script.src = url;
                  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
                };
                Afterpay.init = function($) {
                  $('body').on('change', $('form[action^="/cart/add"]'), function(event) {
                    var $form = $(event.target).closest('form');
                    var $afterpay_paragraph = null;
                    var should_show_instalments = false;
                    var selected_variant_id = parseInt($('input[name=id]:checked, select[name=id], input[name=id], hidden[name=id]', $form).val(), 10);
                    if (isNaN(selected_variant_id)) {
                      var $variant_options = $form.find('input[name=id][value], select[name=id] option[value], hidden[name=id][value]').filter(function(index, element) {
                        return $(element).attr('value').match(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/);
                      });
                      $variant_options.each(function(index, element) {
                        $.each(Afterpay.products, function(product_index, product) {
                          $.each(product.variants, function(variant_index, variant) {
                            if (variant.id == $(element).val()) {
                              $afterpay_paragraph = $('.afterpay-paragraph[data-product-id=' + product.id + ']');
                              return false;
                            }
                          });
                          if ($afterpay_paragraph !== null) {
                            return false;
                          }
                        });
                        if ($afterpay_paragraph !== null) {
                          return false;
                        }
                      });
                    } else if (selected_variant_id > 0) {
                      $.each(Afterpay.products, function(product_index, product) {
                        $.each(product.variants, function(variant_index, variant) {
                          if (variant.id == selected_variant_id) {
                            $afterpay_paragraph = $('.afterpay-paragraph[data-product-id=' + product.id + ']');
                            if (variant.available && variant.price >= {{ afterpay_minimum_value_in_cents }} && variant.price <= {{ afterpay_maximum_value_in_cents }}) {
                              should_show_instalments = true;
                              $afterpay_paragraph.find('.afterpay-instalments').html('$' + (Math.round(variant.price / 4) / 100).toFixed(2) + '&nbsp;{{ shop.currency }}');
                            }
                          }
                        });
                      });
                    }
                    if ($afterpay_paragraph !== null) {
                      if (should_show_instalments) {
                        $afterpay_paragraph.show();
                      } else {
                        $afterpay_paragraph.hide();
                      }
                    }
                  });
                };
                if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined' || parseFloat(jQuery.fn.jquery) < 1.7) {
                  Afterpay.loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js', function() {
                    var jQuery_1_12_4 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
                    Afterpay.init(jQuery_1_12_4);
                  });
                } else {
                  Afterpay.init(jQuery);
                }
              }
              Afterpay.products.push({{ product | json }});
            </script>
          
                      
            {% endif %}  
         
          {%include 'zip-widget'%} 
          
          {% endif %}
        <!-- End Afterpay Liquid Snippet for Shopify v2.2.0 -->
          
                                        <!-- Zip WIDGET -->

<style>
  
  .container {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #shopify-zip-prod-widget > iframe { 
    height: 60px!important;
    max-width: min-content!important;
  }
  
  .sezzle-checkout-button.sezzle-left {
    float: none;
    -ms-flex-pack: left;
    justify-content: left;
    background: #fbfbfb;
}
  
  .sezzle-checkout-button-wrapper .sezzle-button-text.sezzle-thin {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: unset;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sezzle-button-text.sezzle-left {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
<span style="cursor:pointer" id="shopify-zip-prod-widget" data-zm-asset="productwidget" data-zm-widget="popup" data-zm-popup-asset="termsdialog"></span>
<!-- end Zip WIDGET -->                  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For United State customers it should be only showing "Afterpay" and "Sezzle"

That is why I hide other Buy Now, Pay Later options

If someone can help me to get the sezzle-widget below the "Afterpay" widget text it would be greately appreciated.

I am working on Shopify by the way and the theme file I am editing is afterpay-block.liquid

The previous developer has integrated all the Buy now Pay later options in this template file